# How to generate a key from CRT file?

Tags: openssl, wsdl, ssl-certificate, public, private-key

I am trying to generate a key from a CRT file.

I have installed OpenSSL on Windows and tried to get a random key using

[image]

I have the CRT file but I'm unsure how to get keys from it. Inside the CRT file it shows `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the image, note the `OpenSSL>` prompt. It means you're inside `openssl` command and you don't need to type "openssl" again (that's why you've got the message "openssl is an invalid command"). In this case, you should just type `genrsa etc...`

But I don't know if I get what you're trying to do (generate a key **from** a crt file), mainly because: `genrsa` is a command to generate a new key pair using [RSA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). In short, it generates 2 keys: one private and one public. The public key will be signed by a [Certification Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Certification_authority), and the result is a digital certificate (which can be in a CRT file)

My point is: if you have a CRT file (aka certificate), it means a key pair was already generated and signed by a Certification Authority. There's no way to generate a new key **from** it (because it already has a key).

If you want to get the public key that's inside the certificate, you must read it using openssl `x509` command. Something like:

```
openssl x509 -text -in crtfile` (or omit "openssl" if you're inside `OpenSSL>` prompt).
```

PS: this command prints the whole certificate. If you want **just** the public key, you can run:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in crtfile
```

If you want to generate a new key pair, then use `genrsa`.

Comment: thanks for your help with this, inside OpenSSL prompt how can I find my C:// directory so I can use x509 -text -in crtfile?

Comment: You can replace "crtfile" with the full path of the file, I think

Comment: @Samantha, I edited the answer adding an option to get just the public key from the certificate (if that's what you need)